# Insert oracle data based on column position

Tags: database, oracle, insert

Im trying to insert oracle data based on a specific order of my columns. This is what i have tried but i get a sql statement not properly ended error.

```
INSERT INTO owner.users u
(
   select column_name 
   from all_tab_cols 
   where owner ='owner' AND table_name= 'users' AND virtual_column='NO' 
   order by 1
) 
VALUES ('foo','bar')
```

Comment: And what is the problem with using column names?  If you want to do an insert this way, you will need to use dynamic SQL.  But using column names is much simpler . . . that is what they are there for.

Comment: that would be a lot easier, but im trying to write some dynamic code to insert into various tables.